# Odd behavior of to_dict

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I'm building a fuzzy search program, using FuzzyWuzzy, to find matching names in a dataset. My data is in a DataFrame of about 10378 rows and `len(df['Full name'])` is 10378, as expected. But `len(choices)` is only 1695.

I'm running Python `2.7.10` and pandas `0.17.0`, in an IPython Notebook.

```
choices = df['Full name'].astype(str).to_dict()
def fuzzy_search_to_df (term, choices=choices):
    search = process.extract(term, choices, limit=len(choices)) # does the search itself
    rslts = pd.DataFrame(data=search, index=None, columns=['name', 'rel', 'df_ind']) # puts the results in DataFrame form
    return rslts
results = fuzzy_search_to_df(term='Ben Franklin') # returns the search result for the given term
matches = results[results.rel > 85] # subset of results, these are the best search results
find = df.iloc[matches['df_ind']] # matches in the main df
```

As you can probably tell, I'm getting the index of the result in the `choices` dict as `df_ind`, which I had assumed would be the same as the index in the main dataframe.

I'm fairly certain that the issue is in the first line, with the `to_dict()` function, as `len(df['Full name'].astype(str)`results in 10378 and `len(df['Full name'].to_dict())` results in 1695.

Comment: what is `len(df.index.unique())` ?

Comment: 1695. Does that mean that there are 1695 names and the rest are duplicates?

Comment: @nocoolsoft yes dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys :)

Comment: @nocoolsoft yes, as vignesh explained correctly, you cannot have duplicate keys in dictionary, but you have duplicate `index`es in your dataframe, hence the duplicate indexes get overwritten. Are the indexes important?

Comment: @AnandSKumar using `choices = dict(zip(df['n'],df['Full name'].astype(str)))`, where df['n'] is np.arange(len(df)), worked fine and got what I needed. Had some indexing issues because I was importing the data from different Excel spreadsheets. How do I give you credit for your help?

Comment: @nocoolsoft Why make it that complex and slow, if you want that you can simply do - `df.reset_index()['Full name'].astype(str).to_dict()` and get the same thing, most probably much faster as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have multiple rows in your dataframe, where the index is the same, hence since a Python dictionary can only hold a single value for a single key , and in [`Series.to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) method, the index is used as the key, the values from those rows get overwritten by the values that come later.

A very simple example to show this behavior -

```
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2]],index=[1,1],columns=['A'])

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   A
1  1
1  2

In [38]: df['A'].to_dict()
Out[38]: {1: 2}
```

This is what is happening in your case, and noted from the comments, since the amount of `unique` values for the index are only `1695` , we can confirm this by testing the value of `len(df.index.unique())` .

If you are content with having numbers as `key` (the index of the dataframe) , then you can reset the indexes using [`DataFrame.reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) , and then use `.to_dict()` on that. Example -

```
choices = df.reset_index()['Full name'].astype(str).to_dict()
```

Demo from above example -

```
In [40]: df.reset_index()['A'].to_dict()
Out[40]: {0: 1, 1: 2}
```

This is the same the solution OP found - `choices = dict(zip(df['n'],df['Full name'].astype(str)))` (as can be seen from the comments) - but this method would be faster than using `zip` and `dict` .

Comment: This saved my life, thank you so much! Spent hours on it already and this just saved me the rest of the day :-)